# How do I convert an AMD module from a singleton to an instance?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I'm trying to convert a working Durandal view model module from a singleton to an instance. The original working version followed this pattern:

```
define(['knockout'],
function(ko) {

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        companyId: null;
        company: ko.observable({})
    };

    return vm;

    function activate(companyId) {
        vm.companyId = companyId;
        //get company data then
        vm.company(data);
    }
}
```

The new version exports a function so that I get a new instance on every request...

```
define(['knockout'],
function(ko) {

    var vm = function() {
        activate = activate;
        companyId = null;
        company = ko.observable({});
    };

    return vm;

    function activate(companyId) {
        vm.companyId = companyId;
        //get company data then
        vm.company(data);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is "object function () [...function signature...] has no method company on the line `vm.company(data);`. What am I doing wrong? Why can I set the property but can't access the knockout observable? How should I refactor the original code so that I get a new instance on every request?

---

My efforts to simplify the code for this question hid the actual problem. My real code was using Q promises and calling two methods with Q.All. Since Q is in the global namespace, it couldn't resolve my viewmodel after converting to a function. Passing the view model to the methods called by Q resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
var vm = function() {
        this.activate = activate;
        this.companyId = null;
        this.company = ko.observable({});
    };
```

Without any qualifiers to the assignment, those keywords are being assigned to global variables.

However, if this module is already in use by code that you can't easily modify, then you may have a problem, since anything referring to vm would need to know it's a function they need to call.

Comment: I get the same error. I'm not sure you're correct about the global scoping; ReSharper warns on those and it isn't warning me.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-factor it this way:

```
define(['knockout'],
  function(ko) {

    var vm = function() {
      this.companyId = null;
      this.company = ko.observable({});
    };

    vm.prototype.activate = function (companyId) {
      this.companyId = companyId;
      //get company data then
      this.company(data);
    };

    return vm;
  }
```

Comment: Durandal doesn't like this, it can't activate the module.

Comment: Odd. How are you navigating to the view model? Are you doing something like `router.navigate('viewmodels/myview:'+ companyId)`? I have several view models in my projects that use this pattern and it works just as the documentation suggests it should.

Comment: I'm composing a link on the page. I'll check and see if this works now that the original problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
define(['knockout'],
function(ko) {
var createVM = function() {
    var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    companyId: null;
    company: ko.observable({})
    }
    return vm;
};
```

.    var vm = createVM();
    return vm;

```
function activate(companyId) {
    vm.companyId = companyId;
    //get company data then
    vm.company(data);
}
}
```